# How to get the byte offset based on the Video's play time offset in Android?

Tags: android, video, mediaextractor

How can I get the byte offset of a video based on the video's play time offset? For example, given the play time offset of 15 seconds for a video, I'd like to know the byte offset for that second.

The reason for this is because I'd like to be able to "trim" a clip from a video. I'd like to be able to save a video clip from 00:00:20 to 00:00:35 of the video.

At the moment, here is what I have - but this saves the entire video from the url to the device:

```
URL url = new URL(http_url_path);
URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

// Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
// uses 5KB download buffer
InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(is, BUFFER_SIZE);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
byte[] buff = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

int len = 0;
while ((len = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
    out.write(buff, 0, len);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind cutting at the nearest key frame (a/k/a sync frame), you can use [MediaExtractor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html) to extract the frames, using `getSampleTime()` to check the PTS, and [MediaMuxer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) to put it back together minus the unwanted frames.

The video must start with a key frame, so you can't cut the stream at an arbitrary point unless you're willing to re-encode that GOP.

MP4 video files are not just a series of frames (I assume you're not operating on raw H.264 data). MediaMuxer will take care of rewriting the header and other supporting data.

Comment: Thank you @fadden . I've updated my original post with some code on how I am writing the video file to a FileOutputStream. How would I modify this to capture a clip of the video?

Answer (score 1):

You can try INDE Media for Mobile - https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials

It has transcoding\remuxing functionality as MediaComposer class and a possibility to select segments for resulted files. Since it uses MediaCodec API inside it is very battery friendly and works as fast as possible. Samples are here: https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile

[image]